# Angular JS Promises with $http -- looping through returned data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am getting some data from the database by using angular $http. I can successfully get the data but before I can show that data to the user on the front end I want to loop through the data and make some changes.

```
$http.get("/getList").then(function(data  ̶,̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶t̶u̶s̶ ) {
        // setting data to the front end
        $scope.returnedData = data.data;

   },function errorCallback(response) {

    console.log(response.data.message)

    });
}
```

**My Loop function:**

```
if($scope.returnedData.modules.length > 0){
     for(var i=0; i<=$scope.returnedData.modules.length; i++){
           if($scope.returnedData.modules[i].carType === 2){
               $scope.returnedData.modules[i].carModel = $scope.returnedData.modules[i].carModel / 52;
         } else if($scope.returnedData.modules[i].truckType === 2){
               $scope.returnedData.modules[i].truckModel = $scope.returnedData.modules[i].truckModel / 52;
            }
        }
  }
```

How can I chain Angular promises so once I get the data I can loop through it and make changes as I want and after that set it to the front-end.

Comment: You don't need chaining here, you could directly call `My Loop function:` from `/getList` ajax `.then` successCallback function..

Comment: @PankajParkar Thanks for the comment. Should I call the loop function first from within `/getList .then` and then set `$scope.returnedData` to the front end? Im confused about the sequence. Any chance you can provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Just handle the fetched data before storing the result to `$scope` variable:

```
$http.get("/getList")
  .then(function(data, status) {
    if(data.data.modules.length > 0) {
      for(var i=0; i<=data.data.modules.length; i++) {
        if(data.data.modules[i].carType === 2) {
          data.data.modules[i].carModel = data.data.modules[i].carModel / 52;
        } else if(data.data.modules[i].truckType === 2){
          data.data.modules[i].truckModel = data.data.modules[i].truckModel / 52;
        }
      }
    }
    // Storing the result
    $scope.returnedData = data.data;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error)
  });
```

And the similar code with check for existence and `modulesWithCartypeEqualToTwo` and `modulesWithTrucktypeEqualToTwo` arrays for more comfortable debugging:

```
$http.get("/getList")
      .then(function(data, status) {
        var modulesWithCartypeEqualToTwo = [];
        var modulesWithTrucktypeEqualToTwo = [];
        if(data.data.modules) {
          if(data.data.modules.length > 0) {
            for(var i=0; i<=data.data.modules.length; i++) {
              if(data.data.modules[i].carType === 2) {
                modulesWithCartypeEqualToTwo.push(data.data.modules[i])
                data.data.modules[i].carModel = data.data.modules[i].carModel / 52;
              } else if(data.data.modules[i].truckType === 2) {
                modulesWithTrucktypeEqualToTwo.push(data.data.modules[i])
                data.data.modules[i].truckModel = data.data.modules[i].truckModel / 52;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        console.log('modules with carType === 2');
        console.log(modulesWithCartypeEqualToTwo);
        console.log('modules with truckType === 2');
        console.log(modulesWithTrucktypeEqualToTwo);
        // Storing the result
        $scope.returnedData = data.data;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error)
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it but it doesn't seem to work. I get the following error `Cannot read property 'carType' of undefined` I have checked and `carType` is not undefined. I can see it in console.

Comment: @Skywalker, it says that `modules[i]` is `undefined`, not `carType`. Try to add the check for existence of the property like `for(var i=0; i<=data.data.modules.length; i++) {if(data.data.modules[i] {if(data.data.modules[i].carType) { ...`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That seems to have worked. But I don't get it, the `modules[i]` was never empty. How does adding a check fix the issue? So I can better understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @Skywalker, I'll update the answer with check for existence in few minutes

Comment: @Skywalker, check out the updated answer. Did it help you to find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To chain from a promise, **return** data to the `.then` method handler function:

```
var promise = $http.get("/getList").then(function(response  ̶,̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶t̶u̶s̶ ) {
        // setting data to the front end
        $scope.returnedData = response.data;
        ͟r͟e͟t͟u͟r͟n͟ response.data;

   },function errorCallback(response) {

    console.log(response.data.message)
    //IMPORTANT
    throw response;

    });
```

Then **chain** from the returned promise:

```
promise.then(function(data) {
    if(data.modules.length > 0){
         for(var i=0; i<=data.modules.length; i++){
            //code ...
         };
    };
});
```

It is important to use a [throw statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) in the rejection handler. Otherwise the promise will be **converted** from a rejected promise to a fulfilled promise.